# How do I keep the selection that was made on a drop down menu after passing it through the URL in ColdFusion?

Tags: sql, select, coldfusion, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu on my ColdFusion page that filters a list of data based on its selection. The selection is passed through the URL and the results are displayed. The problem is that I would like to keep the selection that was made after the page has reloaded. Right now it goes back to the first option every time.

This is how I pass it through the URL by the onChange of the drop down menu:

```
<cfif IsDefined(url.filterBy)>
     query...
</cfif>
```

Comment: Probably need more information in order to really help. What's your SELECT look like?

Comment: My select statement is as follows: <select name="mySelect" onChange="window.location.href='myPage.cfm?filterBy=' + this.value">

Answer (score 1):

Inside your option tag, you place an if statement that checks the value passed via the form scope.

So:

```
<select name="myDropdown" id="myDropdown">
  <option value="someValue"<cfif Form.myDropdown EQ 'someValue'> selected="selected"</cfif>>Some value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The drop down I have is not within a form, so I can't put "Form.myDropdown". Is there a way around this?

Comment: I see, well you could use the URL scope too - the syntax would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, you just need to see if the existing `URL.filterby` value matches a value in your SELECT.

```
<cfparam name="URL.filterby" value="" />
...
<select name="mySelect" onChange="window.location.href='myPage.cfm?filterBy=' + this.value">
  <option value="option1" #selectIf(URL.filterby IS "option1")#>Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2" #selectIf(URL.filterby IS "option2")#>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

The CFPARAM ensures that there's always a value for URL.filterby. `selectIf` is just a UDF that I use to keep from cluttering my HTML with CFML code. It simply takes anything that can be interpreted as a boolean and returns a string as appropriate.

```
function selectIf(checkVal) {
  if (checkVal) {
    return "selected=""selected""";
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Then the rest of your page can look at URL.filterby and if it has a value, then do your query and display your data.

```
<cfif structKeyExists(URL,"filterby") AND URL.filterby IS NOT "">
  <!--- query here, etc. --->
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I've figured it out a different way (sort of). What I do is grab the String Query part of the URL, trim just the Country Name and compare it the values of the drop down menu.

```
<option value="#CountryName" 
  <cfif #CountryName# EQ #replace(#CGI.StringQuery#,"filterBy=","")#>
    selected="selected"
  </cfif>>#CountryName#
</option>
```

Works good, for the most part. When it comes down to country names with more than one word, the spaces mess it up and it doesn't keep the selection. I tried also replacing the spaces as such:

```
#replace(#CGI.StringQuery#,"%20"," ")#
```

But, no good. Anybody have a solution for this to recognize the spaces?

Comment: Well, firstly I'd be using ID numbers for each option, rather than the full country name - not least for internationalisation purposes, as country names are spelt differently in each language... However, if you're looking to use strings in this way, I'd suggest URLEncodedFormat() would probably help you out. Take a look at the docs here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7bdf.html